# Javascript, first click not animated

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, click

Having some troubles making first click working as I want it.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sach_a/ge9npbqf/2/)

If first state is set to true, first click does nothing, second `clik` brings the hidden `div`. And then it works as it should for next clicks.
If I put first state on false, div will suddenly appear on first click, ignoring css animation rules. Next clicks will work as it should.

What did I miss ?

Comment: I'd add your code here as well in addition to the fiddle. There's a nice built-in fiddle functionality via the HTML/JS/CSS snippet button here on SO.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sach_a/ge9npbqf/2/

Comment: Or better http://jsfiddle.net/ge9npbqf/4/

Comment: Thanks Rajaprabhu, works flawlessly now. Didn't think about initial position, I'm an idiot !

Comment: @beati.pauperes.spiritu Glad it helped you, But try to press the tick mark inside the answer that I given below, if it really helped you. That action of yours will help future referrers to spot the correct answer. And by the way, this is not a compulsion. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial setting of `right` css property should be `-5%`. Also the flag that you are using should be `false` initially.

CSS:

```
.floatbox{
    position:relative;
    width:40%;
    right:-5%;  /* you need to set it initially */
    .
    .
```

JS:

```
states = [ false ];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wrap").click(function() {
        var _id=$(this).attr('data-id');
        if (states[_id] == true){
            $(".floatbox")[_id].style.cssText="right:-5%;";
            states[_id]=false;
        }
        else {
            var _id=$(this).attr('data-id');
            $(".floatbox")[_id].style.cssText="right:20%;";
            states[_id] = true;
        }
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ge9npbqf/4/)